# URL Encoding with ISO8859-15 is converted to Unknown format

Tags: rest, odata, urlencode, iso-8859-1

I have Rest API which sends SMS.

Content of the SMS is in French `“Afin d'établir le tiers-payant pour votre traitement d'immunothérapie allergénique”`
As SMS provider except the msg in IS08859-15 ,So I converted the msg into

```
Afin%20d%27%E9tablir%20le%20tiers-payant%20pour%20votre%20traitement%20d%27immunoth%E9rapie%20allerg%E9nique%2C
```

Here the final call which sends msg

```
https://xxxx.xxxx.com/xxxxxx/xx/SendMTRequest.jsp?UserName=xxxxxx&Password=xxxxxxx$&Content= %20d%27%E9tablir%20le%20tiers-payant%20pour%20votre%20traitement%20d%27immunoth%E9rapie%20allerg%E9nique%2C%&DA=Mobileno&Flags=0&SenderAppId=3410
```

with header

```
Content-Type ISO8859-15
```

What is received on the Server side is

```
20Afin%20d%27%ef%bf%bdtablir%20le%20tiers-payant%20pour%20votre%20traitement%20d%27immunoth%ef%bf%bdrapie%20allerg%ef%bf%bdnique%2c%
```

Can someone tell me why `%E9` which is ISO88591-15 format for `é` is changed to `%ef%bf%bd` ?
and also a way to solve this.

Thank you

Comment: First `ISO8859-15` is not a content-type, although it could be a charset _attribute_ like `Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO8859-15`. More relevant, URLs are NOT controlled by `Content-type`; if non-ASCII they are ALWAYS encoded in UTF-8 and then percent-encoded. An isolated byte E9 is not valid UTF-8, so it is treated as an error and replaced by Unicode U+FFFD, which in UTF-8 is the bytes EF BF BD, which are then percent-encoded. **If you want non-ASCII in a URL, use UTF-8.** Plus you don't need 8859-15; lower-e-acute is also E9 in 8859-1, and thus U+00E9 in Unicode.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : Not very familiar with these content type : ISO8859 OR UTF 8. Do you mean i have to replace é by  "%C3%A9" . I checked  https://dencode.com/en/string/url-encoding  link to verify the format .

Comment: Yes %C3%A9 is 'percented' UTF-8 for that character. In MIME and (later) HTTP, content-types are _types_ of _content_ like text/plain application/json image/jpeg. ISO8859 and UTF-8 are not content-types, but are 'charset's for text that can be used for _some_ (text-based) content-types as well as for things that aren't MIME or HTTP at all and have no content-type. Strictly UTF-8 is a character _encoding_rather than a set, but MIME was designed when Unicode was just starting and existing standards had different charsets but each had one encoding, so then it made sense to label them charsets.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : My New content is url is "Afin d'%C3%A9tablir le tiers-payant pour votre traitement d'immunoth%C3%A9rapie allerg%C3%A9nique"
Display on screen is
"Afin d'?tablir le tiers-payant pour votre traitement d'immunoth?rapie allerg?nique".